# How to specify a custom payment method in Razorpay in android

Tags: android, kotlin, razorpay

First of all I tried to follow [this](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-links/api/new/advanced-options/customize/payment-methods/) documentation but its not working
here is the code which I wrote for it

```
val method = JSONObject()
                method.put("netbanking", 0)
                method.put("upi", 1)
                method.put("card", 0)
                method.put("wallet", 0)
                options.put("checkout", method)
```

i also tried to pass boolean and ("0" and "1") but razorpay page is still showing me all the options. don't know if I'm following the documentation wrong or what.
any help please

Answer (score 0):

I think The JSON you passing is wrong The doc says there is "method" object passed in to the "checkout"

```
"options": {
    "checkout": {
      "method": {
        "netbanking": "1",
        "card": "1",
        "upi": "0",
        "wallet": "0"
      }
    }
  }
```

So your code should be like,

```
val checkoutObj = JSONObject()
....
val methodObj = JSONObject()
                method.put("netbanking", 0)
                method.put("upi", 1)
                method.put("card", 0)
                method.put("wallet", 0)
                checkoutObj.put("method", methodObj)
                options.put("checkout", checkoutObj)
```

Comment: tried, but still showing all payment options